# Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0 In ODE

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to find the numerical solution for the nonlinear, first-order, nonhomogeneous ODE shown below.

```
q := 4835
As := 3.08*10^-4
h := 50
S := 5.6703*10^-8
e := .04
p := 630
Vc := 3514
Temp := 477 
NDSolve[{(q - (h*(T[t] - Temp) + e*S*((T[t])^4 - Temp^4))*As) ==  p*Vc*T'[t], T[0] == 274}, T, {t, 0, 100}]
```

But I keep getting the error "NDSolve: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`"

This ODE is the lumped capacitance method in heat transfer, so I know there needs to be a numerical solution. Any thoughts as to the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Adding Quit [] solved the issue of getting the NDSolve to work. However, I cannot plot the solution. Typing 'Plot[T[t] /. sltn, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 300}}]' give me the following errors:

ReplaceAll::reps: {sltn} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To get started:1) take [the introductory tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour),2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up [by clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine and produces a nice plot.

```
q := 4835
As := 3.08*10^-4
h := 50
S := 5.6703*10^-8
e := .04
p := 630
Vc := 3514
Temp := 477
sltn = NDSolve[{(q - (h*(T[t] - Temp) + e*S*((T[t])^4 - Temp^4))*
        As) == p*Vc*T'[t], T[0] == 274}, T, {t, 0, 100}];
Plot[T[t] /. sltn, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 300}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you some hints.

```
{q = 4835, As = 3.08*10^-4, h = 50, S = 5.6703*10^-8, e = .04, 
 p = 630, Vc = 3514, Temp = 477};

eqs = {(q - (h*(T[t] - Temp) + e*S*((T[t])^4 - Temp^4))*As) == 
       p*Vc*T'[t], T[0] == 274} // Simplify

(*   {0.0154 T[t] + 6.98581*10^-13 T[t]^4 + 2.21382*10^6 Derivative[1][T][t] == 4842.38, 
      T[0] == 274}   *)
```

You see, the T[t]^4 term is more than 10 magnitudes smaller than any other term. If you rationalize to 10^-12, which is much more accurate than the accuracy of given parameters, the T[t]^4 term disappears and you can solve with DSolve. Regard the very small difference compared to strict numerical solutions Tnsol (which also is restricted due to limited accuracy of parameters).

```
eqsrat = eqs // Rationalize[#, 10^-12] &

(*   {(77 T[t])/5000 + 2213820 Derivative[1][T][t] == 4126973296/852261, 
      T[0] == 274}   *)

Tdsol = T /. Flatten@DSolve[eqsrat, T, t]

    (*   Function[{t}, 
    (2 E^(-11 t/1581300000) (-10308442738711 + 
    10317433240000 E^(11 t/1581300000)))/65624097]   *)

Tnsol = T /. 
   Flatten@NDSolve[eqs, T, {t, 0, 100}, InterpolationOrder -> All]

Plot[{Tnsol[t] - Tdsol[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

Difference in magnitude of 10^-7.

Solutions are very close to linear. ( numerical solution restricted too by limited order of interpolation polynom)

```
Series[Tdsol[t], {t, 0, 6}]//Normal// N[#, 6] &



    (*  274.000 + 0.00218544 t - 7.60128*10^-12 t^2 + 1.76256*10^-20 t^3 - 
 3.06522*10^-29 t^4 + 4.26452*10^-38 t^5 - 4.94422*10^-47 t^6   *)

Series[Tnsol[t], {t, 0, 6}]//Normal

(*   274. + 0.00218543 t   *)
```